# NGINX Subdirectory Redirect is not working

Tags: nginx, redirect, nginx-location

**TLDR:** `subdirectory/cool` redirects to `newdirectory/cool`. `subdirectory?cool` incorrectly redirects to `newdirectory` without the parameter.

### The Prob:

I'm attempting to redirect a subdirectory to a new directory while preserving the original URL parameters via NGINX location using the regex `~* ^(?:((\/m\b)(?!-)(\/)?))(?<requestedPath>.*)?$`

The paths such as `/subdirectory/cool` successfully redirect to `/newdir/cool`. However, paths like `/subdirectory?cool` and `/subdirectory/?cool` are redirecting to `/newdir` without preserving the URL parameters.

The redirect should work as follows:

- /subdirectory -> /newdir

  (Many of the suggestions I've seen posted here for subdirectrory redirects assume a trailing slas *or* do not take into account that their regex for /m also impacts /media)
- /subdirectory/ -> /newdir/
- /subdirectory/test -> /newdir/test
- /subdirectory/?apple -> /newdir/?apple
- /subdirectory?apple -> /newdir?apple

The test is successful here: [Successful Test](https://regex101.com/r/c6ZenE/1)

The code that is failing:

```
location ~* ^(?:((\/subdirectory\b)(?!-)(\/)?))(?<requestedPath>.*)?$ {
        return 301 /newdir/$requestedPath;
}
```

Additionally, I have also tried using rewrite instead of location to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, with location, one has to us [$is_args](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_is_args).

This did the trick: `return 301 /newdir/$requestedPath$is_args$args;`

End result:

```
location ~* ^(?:((\/subdirectory\b)(?!-)(\/)?))(?<requestedPath>.*)?$ {
        return 301 /newdir/$requestedPath$is_args$args;
}
```